# Highchart graph display on iPad going out of container

Tags: highcharts

I have created a few charts using highcharts by setting the width of chart to a fixed value of 400px for the normal browser to be used, however, on iPad , the charts get distorted, any pointers for this?

Comment: What do you mean by "distorted"?

Comment: Recreate issue on jsfiddle, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

added following to css

```
.highcharts-container{width:100% !important; height:100% !important;}
```